# JSON doesn't serialize correctly

Tags: c#, json, serialization, types, json.net

I'm extremely new to JSON, but trying to get the following to work but only ID serializes, I suspect I need to nest deeper into the string somehow:

String :

```
{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"result\":[{\"event\":{\"id\":\"27727330\",\"name\":\"Germany U21 v Faroe Islands U21\",\"countryCode\":\"DE\",\"timezone\":\"Europe/London\",\"openDate\":\"2016-03-24T19:00:00.000Z\"},\"marketCount\":24}],\"id\":1}
```

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"event":{"id":"27727330","name":"Germany U21 v Faroe Islands U21","countryCode":"DE","timezone":"Europe/London","openDate":"2016-03-24T19:00:00.000Z"},"marketCount":24}],"id":1}

Class Type:

```
public class EventListing
    {

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "countryCode")]
    public string countryCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "timezone")]
    public string timezone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "marketCount")]
    public string marketCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "openDate")]
    public DateTime? openDate { get; set; }
}
```

Code in question:

```
EventListing Test = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventListing>(theStringAbove);
```

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: Only id is being serialized

Comment: where is the `rpc` coming from?

Comment: It's a feed from Betfair, it comes that way

Comment: the objects don't match - you have a wrapping jsonrpc object you have to account for.

Comment: Again, very new to JSON, first time I've used it in practice.... Would the first serialization call deal with the jsonrpc, then it would serialize the sub properties? How do I got about this?

Comment: Your type `EventListing` does not correspond to the root JSON object.  Upload your json to http://json2csharp.com/, it will generate c# classes for automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I had to create another class, EventResult, which collects the top level data before going deeper into the JSON

```
    public class EventResult
    {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "event")]
    public Event Event { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "marketCount")]
    public int MarketCount { get; set; }
    }
```